# Redirect the terminal dynamic output to a file

Tags: redirect, terminal, pipe

I want to get process progress value of the **diskutil** command when zerodisk on MacOS.

I run below command on terminal:

```
    diskutil zerodisk disk2
```

And it output with progress value:

```
    Started erase on disk2
    [ - 0%..10%......................................... ] 15%
    ...
```

But when I ouput the result string to file by command:

```
    diskutil zerodisk disk2 > output.txt
```

The content of the file ouput.txt have no progress value:

```
    Started erase on disk2
    Finished erase on disk2
```

Can Anybody tell me why? and is there a way to get the erase progress value?

Comment: Is it writing it to STDERR? Try, `diskutil zerodisk disk2 > output.txt 2>&1`. I think that for progress bars like that it may `backspace` the entire line, then redraw it. So, it is writing, then erasing, then writing, then erasing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirecting I/O on the shell modifies the behavior of many applications. Use `script` to capture all of the output to the terminal without interference:

```
script
diskutil zerodisk disk2
exit
```

The output will be in a file named `typescript`.  You can change that using [`script` command-line arguments](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html), e.g.,

```
script redirect.txt diskutil zerodisk disk2
```

The resulting `redirect.txt` will contain *all* characters sent to the terminal, including carriage returns.